# How can I remove all files not containing a string in name

Tags: ls, rm

I want to delete all the files in a directory
which does not contain string in there name.
what command I can use.
I tried

ls * matchingstring * | rm -f

it executes but its not deleting the files.

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution as

ls -1 | grep -v 'Crack' | xargs rm -f

this deletes all the files which does not contain crack

in their name.

Answer (score 0):

sdk's answer works. A more succinct way can be to directly use the ignore option from the ls command to filter out undesired results.

```
ls -I 'ignore' -1 | xargs rm -f
```

This removes all files that do not contain 'ignore' in their name. For more information regarding the ignore option of the ls command, refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51981/ls-list-files-not-matching-given-string-in-filename) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79535/syntax-of-ls-hide-and-ls-ignore).